# segfault variable creation c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I'm having some troubles with a segfault right now.

The problem appears to be on line 122

```
file_stream.read(binaryData, fileSizeInt);
```

The message seems to be unable to create variable object.
I'm using the debugger on CLion, if this is of any help.

I'm fairly new to C++ so please bear with me on this. I've included my source code below, since I have no idea what will and wont be relevant.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//string dataLocation = "/dev/rdisk2";  // Variable for the mounting point of the SD Card.
string dataLocation = "/Volumes/Untitled/data/smith_data_backup.dat";  // Test location
int sectorSize = 512;
int bytesRead = 0;
string outDir = "/Volumes/Untitled/data/readData/";
char data_stop[10] = "Data_Stop";

char* findHeader(char* inputData) {
    int i = 1;

    //look for the end of the header
    while(true) {
        //cout << data[i] << '\n';
        if (inputData[i] == '}') {
            // found the end of the header
            cout << "found the end of the header" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        if (i > 200) { // don't get into an infinite loop here
            cout << "something went wrong here" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // copy the header to a new char array
    char* header = new char[i+1];
    memcpy(header, &inputData[0], (size_t) (i +1));
    return header;
}

int main() {

    ifstream file_stream;
    file_stream.open(dataLocation);

    for( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {


        char data[sectorSize]; // figure out a decent size for this.....
        string date = "";
        string time = "";
        string site = "";
        string intId = "";
        string totalFiles = "";
        string fileNo = "";
        string fileSize = "";

        try {

            // read the data file... this will be fun
            cout << "Reading the data file" << '\n';
            file_stream.read(data, sectorSize);
            bytesRead += sectorSize;

            if (data[0] == '{') {
                char *header = findHeader(data);
                cout << header << '\n';

                //loop over the header to find the date, time, site ID, Instrument ID, and expected file size.
                int commasFound = 0;
                for(int i = 1; header[i] != '}', i++;) {

                    // increment the number of commas that have been found
                    if (header[i] == ',') {
                        commasFound ++;

                        continue;
                    }

                    //check for the end f the header
                    if (header[i] == '}') {
                        break;
                    }

                    //for some reason the first one never gets added
                    if (i==2) {
                        date += header[1];
                    }

                    // append to appropriate strings based on the number of commas that have been passed in the header
                    if (commasFound == 0) {
                        date += header[i];
                    }
                    if (commasFound == 1 && time.length() < 6) {
                        time += header[i];
                    }
                    if (commasFound == 2) {
                        fileNo += header[i];
                    }
                    if (commasFound == 6) {
                        site += header[i];
                    }
                    if (commasFound == 8) {
                        intId += header[i];
                    }
                    if (commasFound == 16) {
                        fileSize += header[i];
                    }
                    if (commasFound == 17) {
                        totalFiles += header[i];
                    }


                    //paranoia of infinite loops
                    if (i > 150) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                string formattedDate = "20" + date.substr(4,2) + date.substr(2,2) + date.substr(0,2);
                cout << formattedDate << " " << time << " " << " " << site << " " << intId << " " << fileSize << " " << totalFiles<< " " << '\n';

                // Read in the data size
                int fileSizeInt = atoi(fileSize.c_str()) * atoi(fileSize.c_str());
                char binaryData[fileSizeInt];
                file_stream.read(binaryData, fileSizeInt);
                bytesRead += fileSizeInt;

                string dateDir = outDir + formattedDate.substr(0,4) + "/" + date.substr(2,2) + "/" + site + "/" + date.substr(0,2) + "/";
                string fileName = dateDir + formattedDate + "_" + time + "_" + site + "_" + intId + "_Full_Data.dat";
                //cout << fileName << '\n';

                //create the directory with the date.
                string mkdirCommand = "mkdir -p " + dateDir;
                system(mkdirCommand.c_str());

                cout << "size " << sizeof(binaryData) << '\n';

                //write data to file
                try {
                    cout << "Write the data file " << '\n';
                    cout << header << " " << strlen(header) << '\n';
                    ofstream outFile;
                    outFile.open(fileName.c_str());
                    outFile.write(header, strlen(header));
                    outFile.write(binaryData, sizeof(binaryData));
                    outFile.write(data_stop, sizeof(data_stop));
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (ofstream::failure e ) {
                    cout << "Unable to write the file " << fileName << '\n';
                }

                //read till the start of the next sector
                int nextSector = (int) ceil(((double) bytesRead)/512.0);
                int startOfNextSector = nextSector * 512;
                cout << startOfNextSector << '\n';
                int bytesToRead = startOfNextSector - bytesRead;
                char dump[bytesToRead];
                file_stream.read(dump, bytesToRead);
                bytesRead += bytesToRead;


            // The first block may be empty, quick check to see if the first block needs to be skipped
            } else if (j == 0 && data[0] != '{') {
                cout << "Skipping the first block" << '\n';
                continue;

            } else {
                //cout << "no start here....." << bytesRead << '\n';
            }




        }
        catch (ifstream::failure& e) {
            cout << "Error" << "\n";
            break;
        }

    }
    file_stream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char binaryData[fileSizeInt];` - that's not legal C++ since `fileSizeInt` is a variable. Use `new[]` to allocate that if that size is "big" - the stack is a very limited resource.

Comment: That would be it, Thanks!

Comment: @Mat I was not under the impression that it was not overly limited, but that it would be too inefficient for the section of the stack containing the array to be dynamically sized.

Comment: Besides other possible problems you have to open the file in binary mode.